# Nested iFrame communication in AMP examples

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to implement an AMP-AD that will render once it has come into view in the viewport based on parent coordinates. I can't seem to use AMP-POSITION-OBSERVER because I'm not using an animation/amp-video.

So following AMP guidelines, I've tried to implement examples using window.parent.postMessage from this page but got cross reference errors:
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-iframe/?referrer=ampproject.org#iframe-viewability

So then I found that in github in AMP it mentions the position in viewport / observeIntersection call, but I still am unable due to cross reference errors.

So then I found "The Exceptions to available APIs" and information on this page:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/ads#exceptions-to-available-apis-and-information

sounds like people are having similar problems.

Are there any examples of people successfully communicating between the parent sandbox iFrame and creatives that are in an iFrame a few levels deep?  I might be possible for me to put my child iframes in the same domain as the parent iFrame, but not in the ampproject.net domain that the AMP-AD iFrame lives in.  Any help or guidance is appreciated.